# Widget is not working while changing the orientation of the screen

Tags: android, android-widget, wifi

I created a WiFi widget which allows the user to Enable/Disable the WiFi and also allows the user to go the WiFi Setting page by one click. In some occasions while changing the orientation the widget get hanged. I can provide the code if needed. 
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [After orientation change buttons on a widget are not responding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574054/after-orientation-change-buttons-on-a-widget-are-not-responding)

Comment: possible duplicate of [After orientation change buttons on a widget are not responding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503114/after-orientation-change-buttons-on-a-widget-are-not-responding)